# How are numbers assigned to a group of real life objects?

Tags: soft-question, natural-numbers

I hope I don't come off as dense but suppose I constructed (informally) the decimal number system assuming the existence of symbols, 1-9 and defining the operation of addition on it with usual properties like closure, associativity et cetera.

Now suppose I have some quantity of real life object say sticks - |, ||, |||,...|||||||||, and I define addition to be the operation of clubbing or keeping group of sticks together.

Question is how is the second real life system equivalent to the first abstract one ? How do I 'see' or prove it?

Comment: This sort of thing can't really be mathematically proven, since "real life objects" are not mathematical objects. What you can do is notice what happens when you repeatedly add a single stick, then use that to define addition by induction, then show that it can be computed in decimal using carrying and so forth. This is a lot cleaner than starting with digits because, I mean, where did all that digit stuff come from anyway?

Comment: You make an isomorphism between numbers and groups of sticks.  Unless you carefully define each system we can't help further.  Note that usually we do not define the decimal system-we define addition on abstract numbers through the PA axioms.  Decimal is just one way of representing these numbers.